# Pass the id from database to in open modal box

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

What I need to do is how I can pass the id depends on id of row to open inside of modal box? I need to have an edit within my table. I have below my table with my php mysql records. But how I can pass the id? Any help will appreciate !

```
  <table width="70%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table-list">
    <tr>
        <th width="40%">Item</th>
        <th width="20%">Category Code</th>
        <th width="20%">Item Code</th>
        <th width="20%">Edit</th>
        <th width="20%">Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $res = $mysqli1->query("select * from code order by item_code ASC");
    while($r = $res->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr>
                <td>".$r['item']."</td>
                <td>".$r['cat_code']."</td>
                <td>".$r['item_code']."</td>
                <td><a href='item_edit.php?id=".$r['id']."'</a></td>
                <td><a href='#' id='".$r['id']."' class='del'>Delete</a></td>
             </tr>";
    }
?>
```

```
<div class="entry-form">
 <form name="userinfo" id="userinfo">
     <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right"><a href="#" id="close">Close</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>Item</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="items" id="items" value="" class="inputs" autocomplete="off"></td>
     </tr>
 <div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       $("#add_new, #edit").click(function(){
           $(".entry-form").fadeIn("fast");
       });

       $("#close").click(function(){
           $(".entry-form").fadeOut("fast");
       });
   });
```

Comment: You can use AJAX to load all you need data with correct ID to your form.

Comment: @AxelPAL can you show me example of that?

Comment: Look at this link: http://pastebin.com/3hFyVBgi. And your getForm.php should contain gereration of your form's HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below idea:

<a href="#" id="someElement" data-id="idVal"> Fetch Value from custom attribute 'data-id' </a>

in jQuery

var someVariable = $("#someElement").data("id");